# Como enviar dados da combobox para uma SGBD sql server?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Tenho uma aplicação onde num dos formularios contem uma `comboBox` com dados preenchidos apartir da propriedade `Item (Collection)`. Como enviar dados que estão nessa `comboBox` para um banco de dados sql server ?

Comment: Bom dia, estás a usar o Razor com Entity Framewordk? Consegues especificar melhor?

Comment: acho que estaria mais para "não está clara o suficiente", e Edson, acesse o [Tour]